# Find $a_1$ and $r$ in geometric progression with given sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$a_3 = a_1 + 20$$
$$a_4 = a_2 + 30$$

> Given this information, find $a_1$ and $r$.

---

I tried a couple of equations:
$$a_1q^2 = a_1 + 20$$
$$a_1q^2 - a_1 = 20$$
$$a_1q^3 = a_1q + 30$$
$$a_1q^3 - a_1q = 30$$
$$30 - 20 = a_1q^3 - a_1q - a_1q^2 + a_1$$
$$10 = a_1q^3 - a_1q - a_1q^2 + a_1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $a_3 = a_1q^2$, $a_2=a_1q$ and $a_4=a_1q^3$. Hence, we have
$$a_1q^2 = a_1+20 \text{ and }a_1q^3 = a_1q+30$$
This gives us
$$a_1(q^2-1) = 20 \text{ and }a_1q(q^2-1) = 30$$
Dividing the second equation by the first one, we obtain $q=3/2$. Plugging $q=3/2$ in the first equation, we obtain
$$a_1(9/4)-a_1 = 20 \implies a_1 = 16$$

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the division of equations so well. Thanks!